# How to get image and track bars to same window in OpenCV?

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing, opencv3.0

I developed a real time image processing program using OpenCV in Python.It have a real time image and few track bars.Those are in separate windows.
How can I get image and track bars to same window?

Comment: how would we know from the lack of info you did not provide? At least add description of your windows ... it is a stream overlay so you do not have the image just viewed instead?   Why are you rendering to separate window when you want it to be in the first one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for createTrackbar in Python OpenCV is:

```
cv.CreateTrackbar(trackbarName, windowName, value, count, onChange)
```

check the following link for more info:
(http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=createtrackbar)

The syntax for showing an image in Python OpenCV is:

```
cv2.imshow(windowName,imageName)
```

Supply the same string in the `windowName` parameter of both functions, and the trackbar will be created in the same window as the image.

Comment: Thanks @Saransh .. But,I want to add my track bars nicely...
I have chosen `tkinter` for GUI..Can you answer this?    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654269/pass-variable-in-python-module