# Pass variable in Python module

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, opencv

I am working with image processing project with Python. I need a good GUI, so I have generated a GUI using [PAGE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/page/).
Now I have three .py files:

1. PAGE generated GUI class file.
2. PAGE generated GUI Support file.
3. My image processing file.

PAGE generated GUI support file defines global veritable for storing GUI component values.

PAGE generated GUISupport.py:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# Support module generated by PAGE version 4.8.6
# In conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Nov 16, 2016 07:58:07 AM


import sys

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1

global frm #this is the global variable
frm=None

def init(top, gui, *args, **kwargs):
    global w, top_level, root
    w = gui
    top_level = top
    root = top

def destroy_window():
    # Function which closes the window.
    global top_level
    top_level.destroy()
    top_level = None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import GUI
    GUI.vp_start_gui()
```

PAGE generated GUI.py. I have added a show_frame() function separately. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342935/using-opencv-with-tkinter) information.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
#
# GUI module generated by PAGE version 4.8.6
# In conjunction with Tcl version 8.6
#    Nov 16, 2016 07:58:02 AM
import sys
import Tkinter as tk
import Image, ImageTk

try:
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *

try:
    import ttk
    py3 = 0
except ImportError:
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    py3 = 1

import GUISupport

def vp_start_gui():
    '''Starting point when module is the main routine.'''
    global val, w, root
    root = Tk()
    top = MainForm (root)
    GUISupport.init(root, top)
    root.mainloop()

w = None
def create_MainForm(root, *args, **kwargs):
    '''Starting point when module is imported by another program.'''
    global w, w_win, rt
    rt = root
    w = Toplevel (root)
    top = MainForm (w)
    top.show_frame()
    GUISupport.init(w, top, *args, **kwargs)
    return (w, top)

def destroy_MainForm():
    global w
    w.destroy()
    w = None


class MainForm:
    def __init__(self, top=None):
        '''This class configures and populates the toplevel window.
           top is the toplevel containing window.'''
        self._bgcolor = '#d9d9d9'  # X11 color: 'gray85'
        self._fgcolor = '#000000'  # X11 color: 'black'
        self._compcolor = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85'
        self._ana1color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 
        self._ana2color = '#d9d9d9' # X11 color: 'gray85' 


        top.geometry("850x500+318+153")
        top.title("MainForm")
        top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")


        self.lblFrame = Label(top)
        self.lblFrame.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.02, height=471, width=764)
        self.lblFrame.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
        self.lblFrame.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
        self.lblFrame.configure(foreground="#000000")
        self.lblFrame.configure(text='''Label''')
        self.lblFrame.configure(width=764)

    def show_frame(self):
        img = Image.fromarray(GUISupport.frm)
        imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
        self.lblFrame.imgtk = imgtk
        self.lblFrame.configure(image=imgtk)
        self.lblFrame.after(10, show_frame) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_MainForm(Tk())
```

This is my image processing code written using OpenCV

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

import GUISupport as guis

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while 1:
    _,f=cam.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',f)
    guis.frm=cv2.cvtColor(f, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA) #this is the variable passed using GUISupport.py

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cam.release()
        break
```

I have run this code. But, I got this error:

```
File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\testforCAmFeed\testforCAmFeed\GUI.py", line 74, in show_frame
    img = Image.fromarray(GUISupport.frm)
AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'fromarray'
```

I need to pass my video and other variable to the GUI module and need to pass tkinter GUI controller data to image processing module.

How to do this?

Comment: you have to use `from PIL import Image, ImageTk`

Comment: you can't run two "endless" loops (`while 1`, `root.mainloop()`) in one thread. You will have to use `threading` module or you will have to use `root.after(miliseconds, function_name)` instead of  `while 1`