# class Image has no attribute 'fromarray'

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, numpy, tkinter

I am working  with OpenCV and Python Tkinter.
I want to get Video frame of OpenCV to Tkinter lable.
I have used Threading, because of I have two loop. (I got instruction from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40654269/pass-variable-in-python-module))

When I  trying to run the code It shows me,

> Press any key to continue . . . Exception in thread Thread-2:Traceback (mostrecent call last):File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 808, in __bootstrap_inner  self.run()  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 761, in run  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)File "c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\defTstWindow\defT
>   stWindow\defTstWindow.py", line 26, in makeGUI img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
>   AttributeError: class Image has no attribute 'fromarray'

I alredy try with Python classes.I got same error.

But, If I run all in one function(like 1st answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342935/using-opencv-with-tkinter) ),Its working properly.

What is the problem of my code?

Now I have four python modules.

1.Support.py

```
import cv2

global frame
frame=None
```

2.CamHandler.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import Support

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def getFrame():
    while 1:
     _,frm=cam.read()

     #cv2.imshow('frm',frm)
     Support.frame=frm

     if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

3.defTstWindow.py

```
import sys
import cv2
import Image, ImageTk

from Tkinter import *
import Support

def makeGUI():

    top=Tk()

    top.geometry("600x449+650+151")
    top.title("Test Window")
    top.configure(background="#d9d9d9")

    lblFrame = Label(top)
    lblFrame.place(relx=0.03, rely=0.04, height=411, width=544)
    lblFrame.configure(background="#d9d9d9")
    lblFrame.configure(disabledforeground="#a3a3a3")
    lblFrame.configure(foreground="#000000")
    lblFrame.configure(text='''Label''')
    lblFrame.configure(width=544)

    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(Support.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lblFrame.imgtk = imgtk
    lblFrame.configure(image=imgtk)
    #lblFrame.after(10, show_frame) 

    top.mainloop()
```

4.main.py

```
    import CamHandler
    import defTstWindow

    import threading
    import time


    threading.Thread(target=CamHandler.getFrame).start()
    time.sleep(1)
    threading.Thread(target=defTstWindow.makeGUI).start()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Tkinter` namespace includes the class `Image`, so when you wrote

```
from Tkinter import *
```

you replaced the definition of `Image` with the one from `Tkinter`.

`import *` can be convenient, especially when working in an interactive shell, but it is not recommended for scripts and bigger programs, for exactly the reason demonstrated in this question.  Change that import to

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
```

(Add any other names that you need to that import statement.)

Comment: Thanks..I replace `from Tkinter import all to `from Tkinter import Tk, Label
`
But,It get only one frame from my camera..What is the reason?
Is it unable to run the while loop?

Comment: You should start a new question for that issue.

Comment: Yes...Its about Tkinter Lable updating issue...I will try to solve it.Thanks.

Comment: problem is solved by myself.
I added a extra function for update image of Label using tkinter after()

https://gist.github.com/NandikaSirinuwan/a74fe868fb0dd8e50908f4cc8692d3de

Answer (score 7):

Better and simple way is change

```
import Image, ImageTk
```

to

```
from PIL import Image as Img
from PIL import ImageTk
```

and

```
img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
```

to

```
img = Img.fromarray(cv2image)
```